# Why _mac folder with some config files commits to git automatically from Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, assembla

I am getting some auto generated commits to my git using android studio in mac and this was not happened in windows with Android studio(Which I was using earlier) Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to disable it?[image]

The commits starts with AI-2.3.2 its my android studio verion 
below is my global gitconfig file

```
    [core]
    excludesfile = /Users/User/.gitignore_global
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[user]
    name = Test
    email = test@gmail.com
[commit]
    template = /Users/User/.stCommitMsg
```

Answer (score 0):

FIX: Open Preferences → Tools → Settings Repository → Delete. I also disabled Auto-Sync. Dunno where it's going to save if I delete everything, but I switch it off to be extra safe..

I just ran into this. Turns out this feature is called "Settings Repository", and it's intended to save IDE settings automatically. I guess I might accidentally agree on some popup from IDEA which look like add files to the git repository, so this started working.